# Grammatical check

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, sentence-meaning

> If you don't mind could you please tell me when will I expect the date
> of joining.

Is this a correct sentence for asking about my joining date?

Comment: The date of joining what? It would be easier to answer if you told us what organisation you are asking. _If you don't mind_ is superfluous; something like _Are you able to give me a date yet?_ or _Could you please tell me the date_ would probably be sufficient.

Comment: It is unclear whether you are asking when you will be told the date, or what the date itself is. For example "You will be told the date next Monday" vs "The joining date is 31st July." As Kate suggests, most of the sentence is circumlocution making unclear what is being asked; are you making two or three introductions to the question?

Comment: If I were forced to assign a specific meaning to the sentence (which is completely ambiguous), I'd assume what you're actually asking is *What is my start date?* and that this is asking a new employer when you will start work. But, that assumption aside, I really don't know what's being expressed by "joining date."